# How to properly fill color inside a shape in inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, fill

I have created a complex shape using Bézier curves, and now I want to fill the color specifically inside the shape. Basically, shape has two segments.

At first, I selected the shape and then filled it with a color, but the color came out of the shape. How can I remove the outer part of color fill on the right side of the shape.
[image: 1213]

[image: zI5qZ.png]

Comment: Your first image didn't make it. I guess only you may heal it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the 2 open paths into a single closed path.

1. Select both paths
2. *Path -> Combine* (<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>). Now both segments belong to a single path object.
3. Edit nodes (<kbd>F2</kbd>).
4. Select (via mouse dragging, etc.) 2 overlapping nodes (the corresponding ents of each path).
5. /Join selected nodes/, which is one of the first options in the node editing toolbar.
6. Repeat 4 & 5 to join the other ends.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your shape into a closed path, otherwise the fill won't work the way you want it to.

In the example below, there is an open path which is filled

Select the object using the Select and Transform objects tool <kbd>F1</kbd>

Next, select the Bézier tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, and hold it over one of the end nodes. When it turns red, click on it to continue the path and attach it to the other open end node. You will be able to see it joining up when the other end node turns red. Click to finish the path.

When the path is closed, the fill will be fully inside it.

Example:

[image]